# Broken plotly installation impacts Django

Tags: python, django, installation, package, plotly

This is just to share some experience.

Recently I have installed plotly for [my Django project](https://github.com/igrowing/Orchids). An attempt of import plotly or any of its modules caused "list index out of range" exception.

After long search, [similar complaint was found @GitHub](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/721).
This seems to be a bug, reported about 1.5 months ago.
The report is about plotly version 2.0.5. I got version 2.0.9 installed. It looks the bug is still persisting. It maybe just incompatibility with Django thus (version 1.10.5).

So I guessed that before that the plotly was working somehow. Tried to reinstall it to lower version.

It helped. How to reinstall --> see in the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix an exception problem of plotly versions 2.0.5-2.0.9 on import, reinstall plotly to known good version 2.0.0.

```
sudo pip uninstall plotly
sudo pip install -I plotly==2.0.0
```